# Python - hiding characters while typing a password

Tags: python, passwords

I have to type in a terminal a user password. googling arround lead to  `getpass` as the most recommended way to do it.

But, somehow- using this function did not hide the characters as expected.
First I thought it has somthing to do with the platform ( Pycharm ), but testing is on IDLE yield the same.

any ideas why ? (code below was on Mac using Python shell)

```
>> import getpass
>>> a=getpass.getpass(prompt='Password')
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
PasswordTHISISPASSWORD
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the password is not echoed when I use `getpass` in python run from the command line on Linux. So I say it is a platform issue.

Comment: `If echo free input is unavailable getpass() falls back to printing a warning message to stream and reading from sys.stdin and issuing a GetPassWarning` - Did you get a warning message?

Comment: What happens if you run the code directly from the shell prompt: `python myprog.py`. Do you get the same warning and have the same issue then?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson since I need it to work both on Linux and Mac - you are correct that for example above was on Mac. following your comment- I check on Linux- and it hides characters as expected.

Comment: @JohanL I updated my question - it happens using shell ( or any other ) under Mac.

Answer (score 3):

if you will launch it from IDE it will cause echo will be seen. You can try it in command line terminal it works fine as can be seen in the attached screenshot.

hope this helps

[image]

Comment: as mentioned above - it happens on Mac, same code on Linux works. why the difference ?

Comment: "If echo free input is unavailable getpass() falls back to printing a warning message to stream and reading from sys.stdin and issuing a GetPassWarning." from https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.GetPassWarning

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code with a terminal and with PyCharm too, it works better in terminal but i found a checkbox in the run configurations of PyCharm that avoid the echoing of the password and set it correctly to the variable as you could see with the debugger, but i noticed that  if you try to print the variable in some cases it prints something strange.

Click on *Edit Configurations...* on the left of the run button and check *Emulate terminal in output console*, it worked with the last version of PyCharm

EDIT: I read just now that you are using a Mac, I tried this with linux, so I'm not sure it will work on mac

Comment: I updated my post after a comment about Linux and Mac.

Comment: If you find the reason for that in Mac- it’ll great

Comment: This "Emulate terminal in output console," worked on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of Pycharm, all you have to do is update your run configurations.

Run> Edit Configurations> Enable "Emulate terminal in output console"

This enables your Pycharm output console to behave as the terminal. Then, the getpass() function works well without echoing your password.